# how to calculate profit in the select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Following is my select query for calculating monthly income and expense

```
select sum(dr)exp,sum(cr) inc 
from vMonthlyExpenses
```

and this will return

```
exp              inc 
$14,751,199.09   $14,800,985.09
```

so my question is how to get profit value along with the above select, Expected result is

```
exp              inc            profit
$14,751,199.09   $14,800,985.09 $49,786.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(dr) exp,
       sum(cr) inc,
       sum(cr)-sum(dr) profit 
FROM   vMonthlyExpenses
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I've already find out this answer any ways thanks for the correct answer